# Why doesn't tensorflow allow me to write file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am a newbie to tensorflow. I have trained a model to classify images by tensorflow, and the prediction works well. However, when I try to write the classification result of test dataset into a result file, it is said that ***tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: File isn't open for writing***.

And here is my python code:

```
import tensorflow as tf, sys
import os

image_path = sys.argv[1]
images = os.listdir(image_path)
f = file("/tf_files/result.csv","w+")
f.write("image,ALB,BET,DOL,LAG,NoF,OTHER,SHARK,YFT\n")
for image in images:
    # Read in the image_data
    image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path + image, 'rb').read()

    # Loads label file, strips off carriage return
    label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
                   in tf.gfile.GFile("/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt")]

    # Unpersists graph from file
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile("/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

    pred = []
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
        softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
                               {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

        pred = predictions
        # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
        top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

        for node_id in top_k:
            human_string = label_lines[node_id]
            score = predictions[0][node_id]
            print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))

    f.write(image + ",")
    f.write(pred[0][4] + ",")
    f.write(pred[0][7] + ",")
    f.write(pred[0][1] + ",")
    f.write(pred[0][3] + ",")
    f.write(pred[0][2] + ",")
    f.write(pred[0][6] + ",")
    f.write(pred[0][0] + ",")
    f.write(pred[0][5] + "\n")

f.close()
```

When I tried to write the first line which indicates ***f.write("image,ALB,BET,DOL,LAG,NoF,OTHER,SHARK,YFT\n")***, it works well. But after calling tensorflow in the program, the statement ***f.write(image + ",")*** is dennied.

Furthermore, I use tensorflow on docker. Is there anything to do with the environment? I don't understand why tensorflow doesn't allow me to write files when using it. And is there any way for me to write files when using tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

notice that your line

```
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
```

is overriding f in your namespace so then
f.write('blah') is trying to write into the already closed file /tf_files/retrained_graph.pb

either change to with () as some_other_f or change the variable name of the initial file you open (or put them in 2 different namespaces)

Comment: Thanks! So careless I am.

Comment: happens to all of us... ;)